# How to convert 2+(2/7) to IEEE 754 floating point

Tags: binary, ieee-754

Can someone explain to me the steps to convert a number in decimal format (such as 2+(2/7)) into IEEE 754 Floating Point representation? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about an arithmetic expression evaluator in assembly code, or what?

Comment: You mean other than just `2.0+(2.0/7.0)`?  Do you want the binary representation of those numbers in IEEE754 and a description of how the addition and divide works, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `2 + 2/7` isn't in what most people would call "decimal format".  "Decimal format" would more commonly be used to indicate a number like:

```
2.285714285714285714285714285714285714285714...
```

Even the `...` is a little bit fast and loose.  More commonly, the number would be truncated or rounded to some number of decimal digits:

```
2.2857142857142857
```

Of course, at this point, it is no longer exactly equal to `2 + 2/7`, but is "close enough" for most uses.

We do something similar to convert a number to a IEEE-754 format; instead of base 10, we begin by writing the number in base 2:

```
10.010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010...
```

Next we "normalize" the number, by writing it in the form `2^e * 1.xxx...` for some exponent `e` (specifically, the digit position of the leading bit of our number):

```
2^1 * 1.0010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010...
```

At this point, we have to choose a specific IEEE-754 format, because we need to know how many digits to keep around.  Let's choose "single-precision", which has a 24-bit significand.  We round the repeating binary number to 24 bits:

```
2^1 * 1.00100100100100100100100  10010010010010010010010010010010010010...
           24 leading bits          bits to be rounded away
```

Because the trailing bits to be rounded off are larger than `1000...`, the number rounds up to:

```
2^1 * 1.00100100100100100100101
```

Now, how does this value actually get encoded in IEEE-754 format?  The single-precision format has a leading signbit (zero, because the number is positive), followed by eight bits that contain the value `127 + e` in binary, followed by the fractional part of the significand:

```
0 10000000 00100100100100100100101
s exponent fraction of significand
```

In hexadecimal, this gives `0x40124925`.